# Web API Async Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing method inside of a Web API controller that returns data from a internal api. This method currently takes around 6 seconds to complete

I need to adapt this method to send up to 4 requests to an external API and then save the results to the database.

Each call to the external API takes around 2-3 seconds to complete.

Whilst the call to the external API is important, I cannot delay the user experience. Therefore calling the external api synchronously is not an option as it could take 3 seconds per call * 4 = 12 seconds, and then will have to call the internal api (5 seconds) = 17 seconds total

To solve this I have made the following changes :

Make the Web API method async
Create a method that calls the external api asynchronously and returns a task

---BEFORE CALLING THE INTERNAL API METHOD
Call the method 4 times, adding the result to a List
Create a timeoutTask using Task.Delay() for 5 seconds;

-- CALL THE INTERNAL API METHOD

Loop through the list of tasks
Call task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask)
If the timeoutTask is complete and the task is not complete, then it has exceeded the timeout, therefore stop processing.

To demonstrate the issue I have created a new ASP.NET MVC Web Api project, and have added the equivalent code to the Index() method on the HomeController.

I have also added an AsyncUnitTests.cs class that has exactly the same code as the Web API method.

The strange thing is that the unit test works as I would expect and the web api call does not.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Example application: [WebAPIAsync.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0SjbSrd3h2N3Y2RHlvNXMwRTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: P.S. If you put a breakpoint on line 16 of AsyncHelper you will find the following: 

- When running inside of the Web API controller - task.Status == WaitingForActivation

- When running inside of the unit test - task.Status == RanToCompletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it!

All `await` calls need to call `.ConfigureAwait(false)` if they are called from any synchronous methods, this ensures it can continue on a different context.

If you are in control of the full call stack and it's possible to make it all asynchronous, this boiler plate code is not required.

However, if you are not in control of the full call stack (e.g. you've written a Nuget package and not sure who the consumer will be) then this will avoid issues.

Comment: the zip requires authorization

Comment: maybe it's better to upload it in Github